# ASP.NET How to use button on modal Pop Up Bootstrap 4 without closing or refreshing popup

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, popup, bootstrap-modal

I have a button on my main page which open popup, in pop up I have gridview, table and button (Add new row) where the user adds a new person in a table and on the button(Add new row) add that new row from table to the grid view. The problem is when the button(Add new row) is clicked popup will close and when open again popup will have that new row in the gridview.
**How to prevent pop up from closing when button (Add new row) is clicked?**

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnOpenPopUp" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-dark btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#PopUpModal">Open PopUp</asp:LinkButton>

        <div class="modal fade" id="PopUpModal" data-backdrop="static">

            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <br />
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label28" runat="server" Font-Size="X-Large" Text="GRID with table"></asp:Label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body ">
                        <div>
                            <table class="table-borderless p-0"
                                border="1" id="HeaderGridView1"
                                style="border-style: None; border-collapse: collapse;">
                                <tr>
                                    <th style="width: 185px; text-align: center">Name</th>
                                    <th style="width: 150px; text-align: center">Surname</th>
                                    <th style="width: 110px; text-align: center">Nickname</th>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div class="container-fluid p-0" style="max-height: 99px; overflow-y: auto;">
                            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                                CssClass="table-borderless"
                                CellPadding="1"
                                BorderStyle="None"
                                ShowHeader="false"
                                ShowFooter="false">
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateField>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Width="185px" Text='<%#Eval("cls_Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSurname" runat="server" Width="150px" Text='<%#Eval("cls_Surname") %>'></asp:TextBox>

                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtNickname" runat="server" Width="110px" Text='<%#Eval("cls_Nickname") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <table class="table-borderless p-0"
                                border="1" id="FooterGridview1"
                                style="border-style: None; border-collapse: collapse;">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="FtxtName" BackColor="#CCCCCC" runat="server" Width="185px" Text='<%#Eval("cls_Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="FtxtSurname" runat="server" Width="150px" Text='<%#Eval("cls_Surname") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="FtxtNickname" runat="server" Width="110px" Text='<%#Eval("cls_Nickname") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div class="p-0">
                            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="AddNewRow_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="False" Text="Add new row" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is code behind:

```
protected void AddNewRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("cls_Name");
    dt.Columns.Add("cls_Surname");
    dt.Columns.Add("cls_Nickname");
    DataRow dr = null;
    if (ViewState["vs"] != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            dt = (DataTable)ViewState["vs"];
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["cls_Name"] = FtxtName.Text;
                dr["cls_Surname"] = FtxtSurname.Text;
                dr["cls_Nickname"] = FtxtNickname.Text;
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["cls_Name"] = FtxtName.Text;
        dr["cls_Surname"] = FtxtSurname.Text;
        dr["cls_Nickname"] = FtxtNickname.Text;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    ViewState["vs"] = dt;
    FtxtName.Text = "";
    FtxtSurname.Text = "";
    FtxtNickname.Text = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve partial page post back while using ASP.NET WebForms, you should use ajax calls or use an `UpdatePanel` to achieve the required task.

For that, put the `ScriptManager` right after the `form` element of yours with `runat="server"` attribute.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

and wrap your modal in the `UpdatePanel` like this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="modal fade" id="PopUpModal" data-backdrop="static">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <br />
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label28" runat="server" Font-Size="X-Large" Text="GRID with table"></asp:Label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body ">
                        <div>
                            <table class="table-borderless p-0"
                                border="1" id="HeaderGridView1"
                                style="border-style: None; border-collapse: collapse;">
                                <tr>
                                    <th style="width: 185px; text-align: center">Name</th>
                                    <th style="width: 150px; text-align: center">Surname</th>
                                    <th style="width: 110px; text-align: center">Nickname</th>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div class="container-fluid p-0" style="max-height: 99px; overflow-y: auto;">
                            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                                CssClass="table-borderless"
                                CellPadding="1"
                                BorderStyle="None"
                                ShowHeader="false"
                                ShowFooter="false">
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateField>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Width="185px" Text='<%#Eval("cls_Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSurname" runat="server" Width="150px" Text='<%#Eval("cls_Surname") %>'></asp:TextBox>

                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtNickname" runat="server" Width="110px" Text='<%#Eval("cls_Nickname") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <table class="table-borderless p-0"
                                border="1" id="FooterGridview1"
                                style="border-style: None; border-collapse: collapse;">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="FtxtName" BackColor="#CCCCCC" runat="server" Width="185px" Text='<%#Eval("cls_Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="FtxtSurname" runat="server" Width="150px" Text='<%#Eval("cls_Surname") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="FtxtNickname" runat="server" Width="110px" Text='<%#Eval("cls_Nickname") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div class="p-0">
                            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="AddNewRow_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="False" Text="Add new row" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

So, the whole body would look like this:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
                <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div class="modal fade" id="PopUpModal" data-backdrop="static">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <div class="container-fluid">
                                    <br />
                                    <div class="text-center">
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label28" runat="server" Font-Size="X-Large" Text="GRID with table"></asp:Label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body ">
                                <div>
                                    <table class="table-borderless p-0"
                                        border="1" id="HeaderGridView1"
                                        style="border-style: None; border-collapse: collapse;">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th style="width: 185px; text-align: center">Name</th>
                                            <th style="width: 150px; text-align: center">Surname</th>
                                            <th style="width: 110px; text-align: center">Nickname</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                                <div class="container-fluid p-0" style="max-height: 99px; overflow-y: auto;">
                                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                                        CssClass="table-borderless"
                                        CellPadding="1"
                                        BorderStyle="None"
                                        ShowHeader="false"
                                        ShowFooter="false">
                                        <Columns>
                                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Width="185px" Text='<%#Eval("cls_Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSurname" runat="server" Width="150px" Text='<%#Eval("cls_Surname") %>'></asp:TextBox>

                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNickname" runat="server" Width="110px" Text='<%#Eval("cls_Nickname") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                        </Columns>
                                    </asp:GridView>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <table class="table-borderless p-0"
                                        border="1" id="FooterGridview1"
                                        style="border-style: None; border-collapse: collapse;">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="FtxtName" BackColor="#CCCCCC" runat="server" Width="185px" Text='<%#Eval("cls_Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="FtxtSurname" runat="server" Width="150px" Text='<%#Eval("cls_Surname") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="FtxtNickname" runat="server" Width="110px" Text='<%#Eval("cls_Nickname") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                                <div class="p-0">
                                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="AddNewRow_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="False" Text="Add new row" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Save</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this still doesn't work for me. Now, when I open a popup and click the button (Add new row), a popup just disappears and the page is locked. I can't even open the popup again until refresh the page. Is there another solution?